# How to create nested serializer for extended User module with user_id as foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework and working on application where I have default User module, then UserProfile to extend it and trying to implement "Favorites" feature and for that reason I added additional table Favorites.

So there is my UserProfile module:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

and there is my Favorite module:

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_favorite', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.ForeignKey('Song', related_name='song_favorite', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I plan to add another field to favorites for movies.

There is my Serializers:

```
class FavoriteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Favorite
        fields = [
            'user',
            'song'
        ]


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "username",
            "is_active"
        )

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)
    favorite = FavoriteSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    ...
```

I also have some create function in `UserProfileSerializer` but I don't think that it is relevant in this case.

I've tried to put this part
     favorite = FavoriteSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
into `UserSerializer` but result is the same.

So as you can see I added favorite into `UserProfileSerializer` and fields should display all fields, but I don't have favorite in my response! There is no error, but it just missing this field

my view for this part is like this:

```
class UserRetrieve(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'user'
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    model = UserProfile
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
```

and urls.py

```
path('api/users/<int:user>', views.UserRetrieve.as_view(), 
name='user_retrieve'),
```

so I expect to see something like this:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 111,
        "email": "4@email.com",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "username": "4@email.com",
        "is_active": true
    },
    ...
    "favorite": [
    {
        "user": 1,
        "song": 1
    },
    ....
    ]
}
```

But my response doesn't have this "favorite" part.
What am I doing wrong and how can I get list of favorite songs?

Comment: I tried your code. Works for me ;) Just checking, you didn't share your UserAuth model - could you add that above?

Comment: @birophilo Sorry, I got confused by names and UserProfile == UserAuth. I've changed it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any direct connection between `UserProfile` and `Favorite` models. Maybe you can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to pull that data from Favourite Model like this:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(required=True)
    favorite = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_favorite(self, obj):
        favs = obj.user.user_favorite.all()  # using reverse relation to pull all favorite objects
        return FavoriteSerializer(favs, many=True).data
```